# How to shutdown host when ansible step fails

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible task that is running the "shell" module. I have the task set to retry x amount of times. If the shell command still does not complete successfuly after x amount of retries, how would I make ansible shut down the host?

Here's an example of my shell command with retries:

```
- name: Check if services are starting
  shell: |
    isStarting=$(ps -ef | grep -c mysoftware)
    if ((isStarting <= 0))
    then 
      sudo systemctl start mysoftware
      exit 1
    else 
      exit 0
    fi
  retries: 5
  delay: 10
  register: result
  until: result.rc == 0
  ignore_errors: true
```

If above task  doesnt detect the software starting after 5 retries, I want to shutdown the host.

Answer (score 1):

Using a [block](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html) with its error handling feature should do the job. Note: I take for granted that the current task is doing the job you expect. Notice I removed `ignore_error` since we want to trigger the rescue tasks in this case.

```
- block
    - name: Check if services are starting
      shell: |
        isStarting=$(ps -ef | grep -c mysoftware)
        if ((isStarting <= 0))
        then 
          sudo systemctl start mysoftware
          exit 1
        else 
          exit 0
        fi
      retries: 5
      delay: 10
      register: result
      until: result.rc == 0

  rescue:
    - name: shutdown server
      shell: shutdown -H now

    - fail:
        msg: "Services did not start, server was stopped"
```